# Get Order Details in \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate

Tags: magento2.4, shipping-rates

We are trying to implement a custom rate shop into our Magento store, using a custom API we developed. This API allows use to determine shipping rates in real time based on the order items and address.

I've extended the \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate object and am able to update the rates we return. In order to actually get the rate from our API however I need access to the order (or I guess it would be the Quote?) object. How would I be able to get the current order (or Quote) in \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a custom shipping carrier by creating a class extending `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier` and implementing `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface.` Your custom carrier class should be located in the `Model/Carrier` directory of your module.

Extending the Rate object is not the way to go, IMO.
Define your custom carrier in the `di.xml` file.
and implement the collectRates method in your custom carrier.

see `vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping` for reference on how a carrier is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It got me looking into using a custom carrier instead and I found this tutorial provided by Magento: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-shipping-carrier/

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired results by creating a new carrier rather than extending the rates. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!